# Android: Location Manager

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

### Run for location updates for different criteria one after another

How can I run for location updates using "requestforlocationupdates" for diferent criteria's one after another.

The problem I am facing is that when I run for locationupdates for say three criteria's, The code begins execution for the first criteria, then a seperate thread seems to be initiated which waits for location change and works with the listener. So before I even removeupdates for the first criteria, I have my second criteria already begining the execution in the main thread and again requesting for location updates using the new criteria. As a result I always can only run the last criteria.

Comment: What exactly are these criteria? Post some code

Comment: What I mean by Criteria is the different parameters for the criteria class - like Accuracy_Fine; Accuracy_caorse etc..

In the oncreate method of my activity I have a onclicklistener for a button which checks which Checkboxes(each checkbox representing a criteria) have been checked. And then requests for location updates for each of those criteria one after another:

Short Snipped would be:

Answer (score 0):

The [LocationManager.getBestProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) function returns you the best provider available. If there isn't a provider matching your criteria, it will be loosened till a provider is found. You can see your definition of the Criteria as an upper boarder.

If you wanna use different Criteria, you can check in the [LocationListener.onStatusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) callback which provider is actual in use. If you don't like the provider (because it's network and you wanna GPS f.e.) there is the place to start a new request for a provider.